# Angular-CLI App-Shell: Getting caught by "catch-all" route

Tags: angular, angular-cli, app-shell

I'm attempting to add App-Shell to my app. I've got a route guard that gets fired during the server build process due to a wildcard-redirect.

**RouterModule**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: RouteOneComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**app.server.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [ { path: 'app-shell', component: AppShellComponent }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppShellComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

Is there a way to have the server-build ignore the wildcard-redirect from the client AppRouterModule?

Comment: Maybe, you should be using a [resolver](https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data) to get data during navigation, not a guard.

Comment: Maybe, but would the http call failing still blow up the server-build?

Comment: It seems as if the problem is not HttpClient, but the fact that it doesn't go to the app-shell route. Tracking the issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue ended up being less about the HttpClient call and more about the routes being called. I'll update the question to reflect. If you're using app-shell right now and your routes have a `path: '**'` in it, you'll need to do what's suggested in this issues's comment:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8929#issuecomment-361884581

Answer (score -1):

Are you using http of HttpClient ?

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"
```

If you're doing like that you should remove and use http of Http

```
import {Http} from "@angular/http"
```

Dont forget to import HttpModule in app.module

Comment: Yes, I'm using HttpClient. Updating OP for clarity.